# Focusing Element in UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a large `UserControl` in WinForm appllication. Some `DataGridView`s are placed horizontally.  When expanding the column width in the last `DataGridView`, the scroll bar moves to first element and I need to scroll again to see the last gridview.

Comment: Not really sure about your question, but you could probably try to put something on the `Resize` or `SizeChanged` event of the `DataGridView`

Comment: And code example also would be helpfull

Comment: Please post the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the issue.